# Personal checks instead of business ones

Tags: canada, check, business

In B.C can a large Hotel company write you a personal check instead of a business one? There is nothing providing the amount taken off for tax or the hours worked.

Comment: By 'personal check' do you mean the payer is a person?  I think you mean the payer is the hotel, but there's just no deductions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are asking about a check for some kind of work or service that you provided them, that they hired your company to do.

**No large business will do that**.

In their records they have a contract with your company to provide services. If they write you a personal check it won't match with the contract, and when the auditors see that they will scream blue murder. Whoever wrote the check will have to prove that you are legitimately the same thing as the company (that doesn't mean taking your word for it). They may also have to show they weren't conspiring with you to commit tax fraud ( that wasn't your intention of course, was it?) .